# How to configurate AWS VPN <-> Subnet <-> NAT <-> Internet

Tags: amazon-web-services, linux-networking, nat, amazon-vpc, site-to-site-vpn

I have set up a site-to-site VPN to a communication provider (for mobile data connection).

They have the subnet 192.168.0.0/21. 
This is connected via vgw (virtual gateway) to a subnet 10.0.1.0/24. The subnet is connected to the internet via igw (internet gateway).

The routing table of the subnet now looks linke this:

```
10.0.0.0/16 local
0.0.0.0/0 igw-xxx
192.168.0.0/21 vgw-xxx
```

So far the following works:

- connection from ec2 instances to the internet and vise versa
- connection from ec2 instances to the mobile end devices and vise versa

Now I need to allow the end device to access the internet.

I thought would need to have a NAT gateway. So I added a NAT gateway to the subnet and replaced the igw with the nat. But this resulted in no more connection to the instances since this only routes outbound traffic (which I later read in the manual).

So what other options do I have? 
How can I configure the end devices (linux) to use this nat gateway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VPC's VPN connections aren't designed to work this way.

> You cannot route traffic to a NAT gateway through a VPC peering connection, a Site-to-Site VPN connection, or AWS Direct Connect. A NAT gateway cannot be used by resources on the other side of these connections.
>
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-nat-gateway.html

The only way anything on the other side of a VPN connection can transit a VPC and access the Internet is to implement a solution where there is no edge-to-edge traffic.

An example of this would be a Squid HTTP proxy server, configured on the client's HTTP proxy settings.  Using an HTTP proxy, the client establishes a connection to the proxy (on an EC2 instance) and asks for a second connection to be established to the destination.  This is two independent TCP connections -- a device on the other side of the VPN connecting to an EC2 instance, and an EC2 instance connecting to the Internet.  The two independent connections are the reason this works.  It is not possible to route traffic directly from a VPN connection to any other type of gateway device in a VPC -- only to EC2 targets and other ENI-based services that explicitly support it.